# Drupal features recreate issue with CCK fields

Tags: 7, entities, features

I have created a form using CCK with conditional fields. If I use the features module to recreate and export the new settings to my staging machine the form comes out flat.

So for example my form is set up to expand other options based on a selection (second option on a drop down box will show different form fields).

After re-creating and sending the files over to staging, same deployment, version and all that for some reason the CCK form appears flat. All the fields that are supposed to be hidden behind certain field selections now appear flat.

So the files that I might have transferred for example after downloading the feature:

```
support_tickets_v2.features.conditional_fields.inc
support_tickets_v2.features.content.inc
support_tickets_v2.features.fieldgroup.inc
support_tickets_v2.info
support_tickets_v2.strongarm.inc
support_tickets_v2.views_default.inc
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue today. After a lot of searching, I found the following patch.
https://www.drupal.org/node/2210241

I was able to solve this using the patch provided.
Can export the conditional field settings (along with content-type & fields) in a feature.
In my case the dependent is a Date field & dependee is a boolean field.

Conditional field 7.x-3.0-alpha1
features 7.x-2.2